# Are the sets $\{\text{fractional part of } n\sqrt{2} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{(m/n)\sqrt{2} : m,n \in \mathbb{N^+}, (m/n)/\sqrt{2} < 1\}$ equal?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

If so, what would be a good strategy for showing that this is true?

The first set is the set of the fractional parts of integer multiples of $\sqrt{2}$.

The second set is the set of all rational multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ that fall in the interval $[0,1]$.

It would suffice for my purposes to show that the second set is a subset of the first set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they can't be the same.  In fact the two sets are *disjoint*.

Assume to the contrary that they have an element in common. Then
$$ n\sqrt 2 - m = \frac pq \sqrt 2$$
for some integers $n, m, p, q$.

However, then $(n-\frac pq)\sqrt2 = m$ so $\sqrt2=\frac{mq}{nq-p}$, but $\sqrt2$ is known not to be rational.

(We know $nq-p\ne 0$ because if $n=p/q$ then $p/q$ would be an integer and no integer multiple of $\sqrt2$ is in $[0,1]$ -- except for $0$, but $p\ne0$ was assumed).